# Simple way of accessing arrays in cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing, cell-array

I'm looking for a quick, simple way of accessing specific arrays that are inside cell arrays. For example, let's say I have

```
A = rand(10,2);
B = rand(15,1);
C = rand(130,1);
D = rand(16,1);
E = rand(1000,25);
my_cell = {A,B,C,D,E};
```

Let's say I want the 1st, 2nd, and 4th matrices only (i.e., A, B and D) inside a new cell array. So the new cell array would be composed of {A, B, D}. This is obviously easy using a for loop:

```
idx=[1,2,4];
new_cell=cell(1,length(idx));
for i=1:length(idx)
   new_cell{i}=my_cell{idx(i)};
end
```

I was wondering if there was an even quicker/simpler way. Maybe there's an obivous indexing trick or function I'm not aware of? I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{my_cell{idx}}` should do the trick.

`my_cell{idx}` returns the elements in my_cell indexed by idx as a *comma separated list*. It is equivalent to `A, B, D`. All you need to do is to close this list with `{}` to make a cell array out of it.

Comment: note. this approach will not work if you wish to preserve structure. Change your original cell to `my_cell = {A;B;C;D;E}` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the heads up about the structure. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can index your cell array like a normal array (i.e. using parentheses instead of brackets). Actually, it *is* a "normal" array: it's a normal array of "cell" elements. So indexing them like a normal array simply returns the individual "cell elements" rather than their *contents*.

Therefore you can just do

```
my_cell(idx)
```

---

**EDIT:** Just to make the difference clear between "indexing a cell like an array" and "collecting the comma-separated-output into a new cell array" approaches:

```
>> my_cell = {'A','B','C'; 'D','E','F'; 'G', 'H', 'I'}    
my_cell = 
    'A'    'B'    'C'
    'D'    'E'    'F'
    'G'    'H'    'I'

>> my_cell(1:2,1:2)
ans = 
    'A'    'B'
    'D'    'E'

>> {my_cell{1:2,1:2}}  % this will ALWAYS be a horizontal cell vector
ans = 
    'A'    'D'    'B'    'E'
```

Comment: Doesnt get simpler than this :) Thanks